# Not allowed to use break since it is a bad programming technique

Tags: javascript

```
function start() {
    var arrNums = [18,23,20,17,21,18,22,19,18,20];
    var searchValue, index, found;
    found = false;
    index = 0;
    searchValue = document.getElementById("searchValue").value;
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML+="The values in the array are: ";
    while(index < arrNums.length) {
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML+= arrNums[index] + " ";
        index++;
    }

    index = 0;

    while (index < arrNums.length) {
        if (arrNums[index] == searchValue) {
            document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML+= "<br/> The number " + searchValue + " exists in the array";
            document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML+= "<br/> The values in this example do match the vaules you must use.";
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        index++;
    }       

    if (!found) {       
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML+= "<br/> The number " + searchValue + " does not exist in the array";
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML+= "<br/> The values in this example do not match the vaules you must use.";
    }

}

function clearOutput() {
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=" ";
}
```

I was told that using break in the loop is a very bad programming technique. That the loop must be controlled by the condition, how do I go about fixing this?
Thank you

Comment: I think you can use `return false;` if what you are looking is to end the loop before the end condition of it mets.

Comment: @Lixus: no. break is fine

Comment: You should avoid *infinite* loops. Thats why people recommend to use a condition, because its more easier to overview, however, just breaking is fine if you know what youre doing

Comment: Of course, the person who told you this is a vastly better programmer than Dennis Ritchie, who put the `break` feature into the language. Right? Ask them to show you the operating system, compiler, web browser or whatever they have written.

Comment: Using `break` isn't inherently bad. `break` can potentially lead to cleaner code than using some flag-abomination to control looping in difficult scenarios. You can run into readability problems though if you have many `break`s scattered all around the loop. In that case, overuse of them can make it more difficult to follow where the loop exited from. That alone isn't an argument against using them altogether though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `found` as exit variable in the while condition, like

```
while (!found && index < arrNums.length) {
//     ^^^^^^^^^
```

```js
function start() {
    var arrNums = [18, 23, 20, 17, 21, 18, 22, 19, 18, 20];
    var searchValue, index, found;
    found = false;
    index = 0;
    searchValue = document.getElementById("searchValue").value;
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML += "The values in the array are: ";
    while (index < arrNums.length) {
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML += arrNums[index] + " ";
        index++;
    }

    index = 0;

    while (!found && index < arrNums.length) {
        if (arrNums[index] == searchValue) {
            document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML += "<br/> The number " + searchValue + " exists in the array";
            document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML += "<br/> The values in this example do match the vaules you must use.";
            found = true;
        }
        index++;
    }

    if (!found) {
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML += "<br/> The number " + searchValue + " does not exist in the array";
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML += "<br/> The values in this example do not match the vaules you must use.";
    }
}

function clearOutput() {
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = " ";
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="searchValue" onchange="start();">
<div id="msg"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML+= searchValue+((arrNums.indexOf(searchValue)+1)?" does":" does not")+" exist in the Array";
```

No need to use loops at all...

About breaks:

You should avoid infinite loops. Thats why people recommend to use a condition, because its much easier to overview, however, just breaking is fine if you know what youre doing...

Comment: While that is true I feel you answer misses the important point about how to properly work with loops&breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I've personally seen some bad uses of `break` in my career, but the break in this case isn't really necessary as it doesn't save you much, but it will save a few loop cycles on average.

Solution 1 is basically the same as your solution, but I would say it takes longer to reason about what is going on than your original solution. Many people blindly say not to use `break` because they think it is just like a `goto` in assembly. It is kind of like that, but when not abused it is perfectly fine.

Solution 1 doing the same thing but with an extra Boolean in the loop:

```
while (index < arrNums.length and !found) {
    if (arrNums[index] == searchValue) {
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML+= "<br/> The number " + searchValue + " exists in the array";
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML+= "<br/> The values in this example do match the vaules you must use.";
        found = true;
    }
    index++;
}
```

Solution 2 just leave out the break and look at everything:

```
while (index < arrNums.length) {
    if (arrNums[index] == searchValue) {
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML+= "<br/> The number " + searchValue + " exists in the array";
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML+= "<br/> The values in this example do match the vaules you must use.";
        found = true;
    }
    index++;
}
```